# not being able to render dom element with custom element in extension--i guess :(

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**the issue is not present and everything works fine if i am not searching for the word's in regular expression explicitly so i guess the url is changing somehow maybe when i am searching explicity**

**when i am activating the extension and searching the words in regular expression explicitly the browser refreshes and goes blank**

I can't find any explanation for this reaction but the links are getting affected somehow (i think ). i was following an extension tutorial of webdevsimplified youtube channel it is suppose to transform every appearance of the words of regular expression to  black background and black color .

```
replaceText(document.body);

function replaceText(element)
{
    if(element.hasChildNodes())
    {
        element.childNodes.forEach(replaceText)

    }else if(element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
    {
            if(element.textContent.match(/coronavirus|covid|covid-19/gi))
            {   
                const newElement = document.createElement('span')
                newElement.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(/(coronavirus|covid|covid-19)/gi,'<span style="background-color:black; color:black";>$1</span>')
                element.replaceWith(newElement);

            }else{
                // console.log(element.nodeType);  
                
            }
       
    
    
    }
}
```